# Cancel nested coroutines in python asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

In my application, I have a coroutine, which may await on several other coroutines, and each if this coroutines, may await on another ones and so on.
If one of such coroutines fails, there is no need to execute all others, that was not executed yet. (*In my case this is even harmful, and I want to launch several rollback coroutines instead*).
So, how do I cancel execution of all nested coroutines? Here is what I have for now:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Foo', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('Foo2 done')

async def bar():
    await asyncio.gather(bar1(), bar2())


async def bar1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    raise Exception('Boom!')


async def bar2():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Bar2', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('Bar2 done')


async def baz():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Baz', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    task_foo = asyncio.Task(foo())
    task_bar = asyncio.Task(bar())
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(task_foo, task_bar)
    except Exception:
        print('One task failed. Canceling all')
        task_foo.cancel()
        task_bar.cancel()
    print('Now we want baz')
    await baz()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

This obviously does not work. As you can see, `foo` coroutine is canceled, as I want, but `bar2` is still running:

```
Foo 0
Bar2 0
Foo 1
Bar2 1
Foo 2
Bar2 2
One task failed. Canceling all
Now we want baz
Baz 0
Bar2 3
Baz 1
Bar2 4
Baz 2
Bar2 done
Baz 3
Baz 4
```

So, I'm definitely doing something wrong. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: you might find RxPy helpful too. Check it out here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you call `task_bar.cancel()` the task is already finished, so there's no effect. As the [gather docs state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

> If return_exceptions is true, exceptions in the tasks are treated the same as successful results, and gathered in the result list; **otherwise, the first raised exception will be immediately propagated to the returned future.**

This is exactly what's happening, a slight modification of your `task_bar` coroutine to:

```
async def bar():
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(bar1(), bar2())
    except Exception:
        print("Got a generic exception on bar")
        raise
```

Outputs:

```
Foo 0
Bar2 0
Foo 1
Bar2 1
Foo 2
Bar2 2
Got a generic exception on bar
One task failed. Canceling all
<Task finished coro=<bar() done, defined at cancel_nested_coroutines.py:11> exception=Exception('Boom!',)>
Now we want baz
Baz 0
Bar2 3
Baz 1
Bar2 4
Baz 2
Bar2 done
Baz 3
Baz 4
```

I'm also printing `task_bar` before the `task_bar.cancel()` call, notice it's finished, so calling `cancel` has no effect.

In terms of a solution I think the spawning coroutine needs to handle the cancellation of the coroutines it scheduled as I couldn't find a way to retrieve them once the coroutine is finished (beyond abusing `Task.all_tasks` which sounds wrong).

Having said that I had to use [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) instead of `gather` and return on first exception, here's a full example:

```
import asyncio


async def foo():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Foo', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('Foo done')


async def bar():
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [bar1(), bar2()], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)

    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()

    for task in done:
        task.result()  # needed to raise the exception if it happened


async def bar1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    raise Exception('Boom!')


async def bar2():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Bar2', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('Bar2 done')


async def baz():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Baz', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def main():
    task_foo = asyncio.Task(foo())
    task_bar = asyncio.Task(bar())
    try:
        await asyncio.gather(task_foo, task_bar)
    except Exception:
        print('One task failed. Canceling all')
        print(task_bar)
        task_foo.cancel()
        task_bar.cancel()

    print('Now we want baz')
    await baz()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Which outputs:

```
Foo 0
Bar2 0
Foo 1
Bar2 1
Foo 2
Bar2 2
One task failed. Canceling all
<Task finished coro=<bar() done, defined at cancel_nested_coroutines_2.py:11> exception=Exception('Boom!',)>
Now we want baz
Baz 0
Baz 1
Baz 2
Baz 3
Baz 4
```

It's not great, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,  it's not possible to automatically cancel all subtasks of a coroutine when cancelling the coroutine itself. So you have to clean up the subtasks manually.
When an exception is thrown while awaiting an asyncio.gather future, you can access the remaining tasks by the `_children` attribute of the Gathering_future object.
Your example working:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Foo', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('Foo2 done')

async def bar():
    gathering = asyncio.gather(bar1(), bar2())
    try:
        await gathering
    except Exception:
        # cancel all subtasks of this coroutine
        [task.cancel() for task in gathering._children]
        raise

async def bar1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    raise Exception('Boom!')

async def bar2():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Bar2', i)
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            # you can cleanup here
            print("Bar2 cancelled")
            break
    else:
        print('Bar2 done')

async def baz():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Baz', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    task_foo = asyncio.Task(foo())
    task_bar = asyncio.Task(bar())
    try:
        task = asyncio.gather(task_foo, task_bar)
        await task
    except Exception:
        print('One task failed. Canceling all')
        task_foo.cancel()
        task_bar.cancel()
    print('Now we want baz')
    await baz()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

returns

```
Foo 0
Bar2 0
Foo 1
Bar2 1
Foo 2
Bar2 2
Bar2 cancelled
One task failed. Canceling all
Now we want baz
Baz 0
Baz 1
Baz 2
Baz 3
Baz 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want. What you did, is actually just duplication of code from `main` into `bar`. I think this by itself is against DRY. But this also cannot be done if I'm awaiting for coroutines from 3rd party libs. Also if you look at this: https://repl.it/EhTf/0, you may see that `foo` subtasks are still canceled. But it doesn't cancel neighbor subtasks if one of them raised exception.

Comment: `not possible to automatically cancel all subtasks` this is why asyncio is useless